# Xfce power manager with sound

Tags: xfce, xfce4-power-manager

Is it possible to add a charging connection sound in xfce4? As in KDE Plasma

Comment: If you're asking about a sound file that comes with Xubuntu/Xfce then yes you can use it in any desktop including Kubuntu/KDE, as the sound file is just a file. If the sound occurs because of a process performed by the desktop itself, then that code may not exist in other DEs, but sorry I'm unsure what you're actually asking about.

Comment: @guiverc Yes, that's what I wanted to know. Thank you

Comment: I think you could apply some udev rule and a command line player. https://superuser.com/q/1417292/490855